# Models not rendering when far away

Tags: opengl, 3d, processing

I am making a game where objects are represented by colored cubes. I have files that mark the location and rotation of the cubes. I've been using Processing's 3D library and the cubes disappear within a certain distance, like this:

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: Many rendering engines have a maximum draw distance. You might want to check out how to increase Processing's draw distance.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [perspective()](http://processing.org/reference/perspective_.html) command to set a greater far drawing distance.

Comment: I don't get how to use perspective. There is no difference between
p.perspective((float)3.14/12, 1900/1000, (float)d.posZ*900, (float)d.posZ*1000F);
and
p.perspective((float)3.14/12, 1900/1000, (float)d.posZ/900, (float)d.posZ*1000F);

What am I doing wrong?